# Wired connection for upload and wireless connection for download

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking

My linux workstation has both wired and wireless connections to the Internet. The wired connection boasts a much higher upload speed, whereas the wireless one has a much higher download speed.

Is there any way to set rules so that outbound traffic is handled by the wired interface and inbound traffic by the wireless interface?

Comment: Your premise is flawed. up/down occur on every link so at best you would have one set of connections up and down on wireless, and a different set of connections up down on the wired. I also believe you are incorrect that the wireless connection has higher download speeds. if there are such limits on the wired connection, they are artificial.

Comment: It's what the internet speed tests say consistently. I should note it's not a true wired connection, I'm plugged into one of those wifi extenders that uses my home's circuit to connect to the modem. What you're saying makes sense though; this was just wishful thinking on my end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Achieving such a triangular topology may lead to problems primarly because the `source` address of outgoing packets will be determined based on the interface. Remote hosts will then use that address as the `destination` address, thus returning the traffic back to that interface that was used for outbound packets.

I believe that, hypothetically, such "boomerang packets" are normally dropped since that would indicate a loop; which is an undesirable trait of a routed network.